# saving objects in collection from a loop

Tags: java, list, generics, collections, arraylist

please tell me how to correct the problem? I've added same object in a collection from a while loop and it duplicates the data.

```
  public class CollectionsFramework {
    private String name;
    private int id;
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    private List<CollectionsFramework> listOfString = new ArrayList();

    public void setListOfString(List<CollectionsFramework> listOfString) {
        this.listOfString = listOfString;
    }
    public List<CollectionsFramework> getListOfString() {
        return listOfString;
    }   


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CollectionsFramework c = new CollectionsFramework();
        int i = 0;
        while(i<5) {

            c.setId(1+i);
            c.setName("abc" + i);

            c.print();

            c.getListOfString().add(c);

            i++;

        }

        for (CollectionsFramework c1 : c.getListOfString()) {
            System.out.println(c.print());
        }


    }

    private String print() {

        return this.getName() + "   " + this.getId() + ";";
    }

}
```

for this, I am getting output as:
    abc4   5;
    abc4   5;
    abc4   5;
    abc4   5;
    abc4   5;

while it should be:
    abc0   1;
    abc1   2;
    abc2   3;
    abc3   4;
    abc4   5;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are using the same object each time inside the loop, and each time you're override its values, so it will print the last value that have been set.

So try to declare a new object each time inside the `while` loop.

```
while(i<5) {
    CollectionsFramework c = new CollectionsFramework();
    // code.
}
```